# データの集計について

Tags: python

#### 実現したいこと

Webサーバのアクセスログから送信元IP、宛先IP、宛先ポート番号、TCP/UDPの項目で整理したCSVファイルを取得しました。

データ内にそれぞれの要素（送信元IP、宛先IP、宛先ポート番号、TCP/UDP）の組み合わせが何件あるかを集計したい。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

#### これまでに試したこと

PythonのPandasで以下のようなコードを使い、データの集計はできましたが、TCP/UDPの情報が集計データから消えてしまったため、TCP/UDPのデータを残しつつ、集計したい。

```
pd.pivot_table(index="送信元IP", columns=["宛先IP","宛先ポート番号"],margins=True, margins_name="合計", aggfunc="count")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

※ データを1行増やしています

```py
import pandas as pd
import io

csv_data = '''
送信元IP,宛先IP,宛先ポート番号,TCP/UDP
1.1.1.1,3.3.3.3,53,6
2.2.2.2,9.9.9.9,54,17
4.4.4.4,10.10.10.10,56,6
1.1.1.2,3.3.3.3,57,17
2.2.2.3,9.9.9.9,59,6
4.4.4.4,10.10.10.10,56,6
'''
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(csv_data))

#
dfx = df.groupby(df.columns.tolist(), as_index=False).size().rename({'size': '合計'}, axis=1)
print(dfx)
```

| 送信元IP | 宛先IP | 宛先ポート番号 | TCP/UDP | 合計 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1.1.1.1 | 3.3.3.3 | 53 | 6 | 1 |
| 1.1.1.2 | 3.3.3.3 | 57 | 17 | 1 |
| 2.2.2.2 | 9.9.9.9 | 54 | 17 | 1 |
| 2.2.2.3 | 9.9.9.9 | 59 | 6 | 1 |
| 4.4.4.4 | 10.10.10.10 | 56 | 6 | 2 |

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。無事TCP/UDPのデータを残しつつ集計することができました。